# Android listview item click effecting on multiple items

Tags: android, listview, dialog, position

I have a product list. I can set order quantity for per item. For this, I have used dialog and item position. 
But when I'm putting quantity for a single item it affecting in multiple items.

[Problem Video](https://youtu.be/SKTHAPZafF8)
I have used bellow code

```
sListview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(OrderEntryActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.order_qty_collect);


        TextView tvpid= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pId);
        TextView tVpid= (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.pcode);
        PRODUCTID=tvpid.getText().toString();
        tVpid.setText(PRODUCTID);

        final TextView parentitemid= (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.parentitemid);
        parentitemid.setText( String.valueOf(position));

        TextView tvpname= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pName);
        TextView tVpname= (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.pName);
        tVpname.setText(tvpname.getText());

        TextView tvpprice= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pPrice);
        TextView tVpprice= (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.pPrice);
        TextView pQty= (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.poQty);
        tVpprice.setText(tvpprice.getText());
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();

        Button submit = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_qtySubmit);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView PIid= (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.parentitemid);
                int ItemPogision =Integer.parseInt(PIid.getText().toString());

                EditText qTy= (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.qtyId);
                String qtY=qTy.getText().toString();
                if(qtY.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(OrderEntryActivity.this,"Order Quantity Blank. Please fillup.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Integer Qty= Integer.parseInt(qtY);
                    salesDB.deleteTmpOrderByPID(PRODUCTID);
                  Boolean x=salesDB.TmpOrderInsert(CUSTID,PRODUCTID,Qty);
                  if(x==true){
                      TextView pqty= (TextView) sListview.getChildAt(ItemPogision).findViewById(R.id.poQty);
                      pqty.setText(qtY);
                      sListview.getChildAt(ItemPogision).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                      Toast.makeText(OrderEntryActivity.this,"Added to Cart",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      dialog.dismiss();
                      Count++;
                      count.setText(Count.toString());
                  }else{
                      Toast.makeText(OrderEntryActivity.this,"Fail to add into Cart",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }

                }
            }
        });

        Button close = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

In the video you can see that, there I have put order quantity for two product but it affecting multiple products from the item list.

Comment: Please forget about the above code. Download the source.

[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ioKWv0oJ21xd8NMZ9jNMJWnQVyX_jMyP)

**Download source.
**Run it, click on an item and scroll the list.

Answer (score 0):

I could't understand totally what you're saying
But,
If you wanna set ClickListeners or do anything in a specific row of the ListView or a specific item in that row,you should set the listeners in the ListAdapter and that'll work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would use getItemAtPosition()

```
sListview.setClickable(true);
sListview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Object o = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
    /* write you handling code*/  
  }
});
```

Your code is potentially picking up other controls as they all have the same id, I haven't delved in to your code too much but it appears there is your issue.

Comment: Okay, Forget everything.
 If I write
`sListview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
        });`
 What will happen?? If I not wrong, the particular item background color will be changed. But it's not happening. It changing the background of multiple items

Comment: Should just be the view that was touched, when you tried it it changed multiple items?

Comment: Try `sListView.getItemAtPosition(position)` like I said in my answer, or `sListView.getChildAt(position)`

Comment: I also tried with your code, but the result is the same. When I touched an item, it's changing its background color with other random items.
if you have time please [download example source](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ioKWv0oJ21xd8NMZ9jNMJWnQVyX_jMyP)

Comment: Try using an adapter then, after a little more digging, the listview is recycling the IDs. So, something along the lines of: `lv.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter()
{
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    { //Do Stuff }}`